Does Ingress overlap some of the NodePort / LoadBalancer services functionalities?
There is this article article with description of Ingress:

Although pods and services have their own IP addresses on Kubernetes,
these IP addresses are only reachable within the Kubernetes cluster and not accessible to the outside clients. The Ingress object in
Kubernetes, although still in beta, is designed to signal the
Kubernetes platform that a certain service needs to be accessible to
the outside world and it contains the configuration needed such as an
externally-reachable URL, SSL, and more.

Is this actually a thing that Ingress was necessary to be introduced to make a service accessible to the outside world?
There is another article with description of NodePort:

NodePort - Exposes the Service on the same port of each selected Node
in the cluster using NAT. Makes a Service accessible from outside
the cluster using < NodeIP >:< NodePort >. Superset of ClusterIP.

It looks like NodePort also makes a service accessible from outside of the cluster. There is also a LoadBalancer kind of service which as an extension should also serve this purpose. I assume there might be some functionalities of Ingress that NodePort / LoadBalancer services do not cover but to me it looks like some architectural choices during the development of kubernetes lead to overlap in the functionalities offered by this platform which leads to confusion. Am I wrong?

Ingress can do HTTP host- and path-based routing.  In a multi-service application, you can provide a single HTTP service where http://cluster.example.com/a/ and http://cluster.example.com/b/ get routed to different Kubernetes Service inside the cluster.
A LoadBalancer-type Service requires an external load balancer, and you'll have a different host name per service.  Your local environment may require a specific set of annotations to get an external host name or TLS certificates.  But, it can support any TCP-based protocol, not specifically HTTP.
A NodePort-type Service requires direct access to the Kubernetes nodes, and you wouldn't normally use it in a production environment.
Since the article you cite was written, Ingress has progressed from "beta" to "stable" (Kubernetes 1.19) to "a little limited and likely to be replaced".  For basic HTTP routing Ingress works fine, but for many even slightly complex cases you need ingress-controller-specific annotations on the Ingress object, which will be different for Nginx vs. Contour vs. something else.  The Gateway API is the still newer version of this, again specialized for HTTP routing.
For typical production-oriented workloads, I'd use an Ingress object to expose services' HTTP endpoints (or a gateway HTTPRoute, or maybe something more specialized like an Istio VirtualService), and I'd avoid NodePort- or LoadBalancer-type services, except on the single ingress controller.
